# Python: Display returned text from function using buttons and labels

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am creating a program to generate different exercises to help with weight loss. A function generates an exercise, and the amount of that exercise you should do. I am displaying these using labels in a tkinter window.

There is also a button in the window, which when clicked should call the function and display the exercise and amount in the labels.

Is it possible to do this?

````
from tkinter import *
import random as r

exercises = ["star jumps", "press ups", "sit ups", "burpees", "bicycle crunches"] #array of exercises
eChoice = "" #declare variable for exercise choice
amount = "" #declare variable for amount of exercises
def exercise():
    x = r.randint(1, 4)
    if x == 1:
        #exercise
        eChoice = r.choice(exercises)
        amount = r.randint(10, 30)
    elif x == 2:
        #walk
        eChoice = "walk"
        amount = r.randint(1,3) #miles
    elif x == 3:
        #cycle
        eChoice = "cycle"
        amount = r.randint(1,3) #miles
    else:
        #swim
        eChoice = "swim"
        amount = r.randint(5,10) #lengths of a pool
    return eChoice, amount


myGUI = Tk() #create window

myGUI.title("Weight Loss Program") #title of the window
myGUI.configure(bg="deepskyblue") #background colour
exerciseButton = Button(myGUI, text="Generate Exercise", fg="mediumpurple", command=exercise) #create button that calls exercise function
exerciseButton.pack()
name = "Name: ", eChoice
exerciseLabel = Label(myGUI, text=name, fg="mediumpurple") #create label for exercise name
exerciseLabel.pack()
description = "Amount: ", amount
exerciseDescription = Label(myGUI, text=description, fg="mediumpurple") #create label for exercise name
exerciseDescription.pack()

myGUI.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exercise function is returning values back to the caller. Instead of returning values you should modify the variables that need to be modified within the function. In this example I've made global references to the variables, but you could also include them as parameters to the function and so access them in a local scope.

Solution:

```
from tkinter import *
import random as r

exercises = ["star jumps", "press ups", "sit ups", "burpees", "bicycle crunches"] #array of exercises
eChoice = "" #declare variable for exercise choice
amount = "" #declare variable for amount of exercises
def exercise():
    global exerciseLabel
    global exerciseDescription
    global eChoice

    x = r.randint(1, 4)
    if x == 1:
        #exercise
        eChoice = r.choice(exercises)
        amount = r.randint(10, 30)
    elif x == 2:
        #walk
        eChoice = "walk"
        amount = r.randint(1,3) #miles
    elif x == 3:
        #cycle
        eChoice = "cycle"
        amount = r.randint(1,3) #miles
    else:
        #swim
        eChoice = "swim"
        amount = r.randint(5,10) #lengths of a pool


    exerciseLabel.configure(text="Name: " + eChoice)
    exerciseDescription.configure(text="Amount: " + str(amount))


myGUI = Tk() #create window

myGUI.title("Weight Loss Program") #title of the window
myGUI.configure(bg="deepskyblue") #background colour
exerciseButton = Button(myGUI, text="Generate Exercise", fg="mediumpurple", command=exercise) #create button that calls exercise function
exerciseButton.pack()
name = "Name: " + eChoice
exerciseLabel = Label(myGUI, text=name, fg="mediumpurple") #create label for exercise name
exerciseLabel.pack()
description = "Amount: " + amount
exerciseDescription = Label(myGUI, text=description, fg="mediumpurple") #create label for exercise name
exerciseDescription.pack()

myGUI.mainloop()
```